# How to center and bold text in the Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Please can you help me center the sentence I entered there, as well as make the word "Description" bold. I tried to center it, but it didn't work.

Thank you very much!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                             
                                   br(),
                                   hr(),
                               
                                   p(style="text-align:center",
                                   h2("Project Description"))))
  
                                  
                                

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HTML` and `<b>` tags to make a text bold.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 
                                 br(),
                                 hr(),
                                 
                                 h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
                                    style="text-align:center")))




server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]